# jQuery remove class on href

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having a list of elements that I'm displaying in the UI as below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#menu ul li.current').click(function() {
            $("li").addClass("current");
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/practiceexams">Practice Exams</a></li>
        <li><a href="/articles">Technology Articles</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When any of the above link is clicked, I want to add the class to that li element. From what I tried above, the class is not added. I'm sure I'm missing something very basic. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: The page redirects to the page in the anchor, and all javascript is lost, so this can't be done that way, unless you no longer want the links to redirect.

Comment: Also, you're targeting LI's with the class `.current`, which none of them have, and if they had that class, why would you need to add it.

Comment: @adeneo: I think that's just pseudo-code; the way I read the question he wants to style the *link* that *links to the current page*.

Comment: Exactly, I want to style the link that links to the current page!

Comment: Then you have to compare it to the current window.location on pageload, not use a click handler, which was sort of my point to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd *suggest*, though this is untested:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu a').filter(function(){
        return this.href == window.location.href;
    }).parent().addClass('current');
});
```

And then style that parent `li`, with CSS:

```
li.current {
    font-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @adeneo; I should've caught that :)

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! :)

Comment: Time to get some jquery basics refreshed!

Comment: May be another question. If I have some other href links on the main page (say /articles), how can I retain the style? I just noticed that the style vanishes as soon as I click on any other links from my main page.

Comment: It shouldn't, unless you have a click-handler somewhere removing/adding classes? The way this works is that the class is *added*, there's nothing here, in my answer, that would remove that class. And while the class is there, then the style should remain consistent.

Comment: Strange. I checked the rendered html using firebug and I do not see the style added anymore to the li

Comment: The reason being that when I click on the link from the list above, the url looks like http://localhost:9000/articles but when I click on any link in the articles page, it goes to http://localhost:9000/articles/100/?pageSize=10 and the condition, this.href == window.location.href fails.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe so?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#menu ul li').click(function() {
            $(this).addClass("current");
        });
    });
</script>
```

but if it isn't a pseudo code you should handle the click events of the a-tags to prevent them from redirecting the page

Comment: Did you read any of the comments to the question that explain why this won't, and *can't*, work to solve the problem the OP has?

Comment: @DavidThomas Maybe you can also explain what exactly does not work in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/hg94h/ ?  It is not a right way to do it, I would never do it this way, but it is the solution for that what exactly the author asked.

Comment: The OP wants to style the link that links to the current page; using a click-handler can't do that (since the class will be added, but the page will be lost as the browser loads a new document).